# Значение в @Html.EditorFor по умолчанию в ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Доброго времени суток! Не могу разобраться как установить для поле значение по умолчанию в проекте asp.net  mvc 4. Пробовал присваивать через:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Category, new { @Value = "5" }
```

Но ничего не происходить, пытался добавить через

```
int _propertyValue = 5;
 public int id_Category{
   get
   {
      return _propertyValue;   
   }
   set
   {
       _propertyValue = value;
   }
}
```

Вроде как можно предопределить через контроллер, в блоке GET, но тоже не выходит.Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно это реализовать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем разобрался, если кто-то сталкнётся, вот решение :

Обработку необходимо добавить в контроллер перед вызовом View :

```
public int value = 10;
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            Category_table category_table = new Category_table();
            category_table.id_Category = value;
                   return View(category_table);
    }
```